# Can anyone help me DRY this REGEX?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my first question (although I have found many perfect solutions to questions on Stack Overflow in the past - it is my first source for help).

I have text strings that contain a month and a series of date. Sometimes, there are two months in the string.

```
date1 = "January 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24"
date2 = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, October 2, 3, 4, 10, 11"
```

I wrote a very WET piece of code that pulls the month from the string and adds each date, plus the year.
However, there are several issues I just can't figure out.

1. ITERATING THROUGH THE DATES: I know I should use the EACH method to iterate through the dates. I tried but I can't get that to work, so I am doing it the hard way by concatenating the month with each date element. The obvious problem with this is, I don't know how many dates there will be so I have to build to the longest string and use an IF Statement to determine if I've reached the end of the string. I should use dates1.length = x plus DO EACH, but I can't get it to work.
2. CONCATENATING MONTH DAY YEAR: My very bad wet code works as far as pulling the month day and year together, but how do I get rid of the brackets and quotes?
3. MULTIPLE MONTHS: How do I choose the second month in the string, and concatenate ONLY the individual dates that follow the month name to get MONTH/DD/YY?

Here is a sample of my very bad code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

date1 = "January 9, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 22, 23, 24"
date2 = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, October 2, 3, 4, 10, 11"
datetext = date1.scan(/([\w\-]+)/)     #=> pulls the whole string 
datetext2 = date1.scan(/(\w*)\s?/)[0]  #=> this pulls the month
datenumbers = date1.scan(/(\d+)/)
firstdate = datenumbers[0]             #=> the first date following the first month
seconddate = datenumbers[1]
year = "2014"

mdy1 = "#{datetext2} #{firstdate} #{year}"
mdy2 = "#{datetext2} #{seconddate} #{year}"

puts date1
puts " "
puts datetext2 #=> this variable adds the [0] delimiter to pull the 1st month
puts firstdate
puts " "
puts mdy1
puts mdy2
puts " "
```

Comment: Gary, here are a couple of suggestions about the writing of questions: 1. eliminate all extraneous statements (e.g., the three `require` statements here); 2. when you give an example (examples are good), always show the desired result, and when applicable, the incorrect result you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do the following.

**Code**

```
def extract_dates_by_month(str)
  str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+/).each_with_object([]) { |e,b|
    e[0][/[A-Z]/] ? b << [e,[]] : b.last.last << e }
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, October 2, 3, 4, 10, November 3, 12, 17"
extract_dates_by_month(str)
  #=> [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]],
  #    ["October", ["2", "3", "4", "10"]],
  #    ["November", ["3", "12", "17"]]]
```

**Explanation**

The first step is extracting the month names and days:

```
a = str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+/)
  #=> ["September", "19", "20", "25", "26", "October", "2", "3", "4", "10",
  #    "November", "3", "12", "17"]
```

We then divide this array up into months:

```
a.each_with_object([]) { |e,b| e[0][/[A-Z]/] ? b << [e,[]] : b.last.last << e }
  #=> [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]],
  #    ["October", ["2", "3", "4", "10"]],
  #    ["November", ["3", "12", "17"]]]
```

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) creates an initially-empty array for the block variable `b` and that array is returned by the method. Each element of `a` is passed into the block and referenced by the block variable `e`. The following operations are performed:

```
b = []
e = "September"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> "S"
b << [e,[]]   #=> [["September", []]]

e = "19"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> nil
b.last.last << e
b             #=> [["September", ["19"]]]

e = "20"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> nil
b.last.last << e
b             #=> [["September", ["19", "20"]]]

e = "25"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> nil
b.last.last << e
b             #=> [["September", ["19", "20", "25"]]]

e = "26"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> nil
b.last.last << e
b             #=> [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]]]

e = "October"
e[0][/[A-Z]/] #=> "O"
b << [e,[]]   #=> [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]], ["October", []]]
```

and so on.

If you want the days to be integers, change:

```
b.last.last << e
```

to:

```
b.last.last << e.to_i
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on writing questions and especially for taking me step by step though what you did, Cary. I'll try your suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Oh, you asked me what the desired result is. I want to assemble each of the strings into dates i can work with using Time.parse and strftime. So, for "a" I would like to ultimately end up with "September 19, 2014, September 20, 2014, September 25, 2014, September 26, 2014, October 2, 2014, etc. Then I will use strftime to get Day of the week (i.e., Saturday, September 20, 2014, etc.).

Comment: UPDATE - after working with the Regex supplied by Cary for sometime (thank you!), I realized it is dropping the last date in the string when I run it in IRB. Here is the code i run and the output. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

str = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, October 2, 3, 4, 10, November 3, 12, 17"

dates=str.scan(/\D+(?:\d+,\s+)+/).map { |s| [ s[/[a-z]+/i], s.scan(/\d+/) ] }

p dates                                                               The output is the following. As you can see, NOVEMBER only returns 2 dates but there are 3 in the string. It drops NOVEMBER 17.                                               [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]], ["October", ["2", "3", "4", "10"]], ["November", ["3", "12"]]]

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\nokogiri>

Comment: I fixed the problem, but in doing so decided to change the approach to what I consider to be an improvement.

Comment: Thank you Cary - the new solution works perfectly. Merry Christmas!