# Regex drops the last character in the string

Tags: ruby, regex

After working with a Regex supplied by Cary (thank you!), I realized it is dropping the last date in the string when I run it in IRB. Here is the code and the output. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'nokogiri' 
require 'open-uri' 

str = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, October 2, 3, 4, 10, November 3, 12, 17" 
dates=str.scan(/\D+(?:\d+,\s+)+/).map { |s| [ s[/[a-z]+/i], s.scan(/\d+/) ] } 

p dates
```

The output is the following. As you can see, November only returns 2 dates but there are 3 in the string. It drops November 17.

```
 [["September", ["19", "20", "25", "26"]], ["October", ["2", "3", "4", "10"]], ["November", ["3", "12"]]]
```

C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\nokogiri> –

Comment: I fixed the error in my [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086602/can-anyone-help-me-dry-this-regex/26087594#comment43610779_26087594) and also changed the approach, I think for the better. It is now `str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]+|\d+/).each_with_object([]) { |e,b| e[0][/[A-Z]/] ? b << [e,[]] : b.last.last << e }`.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably solve the problem:

```
dates=str.scan(/\D+(?:\d+(?:,\s+|$))+/).map { |s| [ s[/[a-z]+/i], s.scan(/\d+/) ] }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Actually, Cary Swoveland's answer worked perfectly, but I don't know how to accept a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The last string does not end with `, \s+`.

You need to create a case for the end of the string:

```
str = "September 19, 20, 25, 26, October 2, 3, 4, 10, November 3, 12, 17" 
dates=str.scan(/\D+(?:\d+(?:,\s+|$))+/).map { |s| [ s[/[a-z]+/i], s.scan(/\d+/) ] } 

p dates
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `,\s+` portion of the regular expression [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html): `(?:,\s+)?`. Put together:

```
str.scan(/\D+(?:\d+(?:,\s+)?)+/) ...
```

It uses a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group) so it doesn't interfere with how the `scan` method works.